# Stackoverflow banners, is it possible?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I wanted to know how StackOverflow banners are generated -like the site moderators' in https://stackoverflow.com/about- and if it's possible to include something like a HTML code in your web/blog/anything for viewing your profile like that.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the flair?
Go to your user page and click `got flair?`

Comment: Yes, it was that. Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: There are debates if questions can be silly. My answers are!